# Android Animation stops unexpectedly

Tags: android, android-animation

I have created following animation :

```
public class MarginAnimation extends Animation {

    private final int fromX;
    private final int toX;
    private final View view;

    public MarginAnimation(final View view, final int fromX, final int toX) {
        this.fromX = fromX;
        this.toX = toX;
        this.view = view;
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        MPLog.debug("Animation","interpolatedTime = "+interpolatedTime);
        setMargin(Math.round(fromX + (toX - fromX) * interpolatedTime));
    }

    private void setMargin(int margin){
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
        params.rightMargin = margin;
        view.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

}
```

but here I found that my animation stops sometimes. Here are logs :

```
02-22 13:14:44.138 25395-25395/com.test.test D/Animation: Start
02-22 13:14:44.148 25395-25395/com.test.test D/Animation: interpolatedTime = 0.0
02-22 13:14:44.148 25395-25395/com.test.test D/Animation: interpolatedTime = 0.0
02-22 13:14:44.163 25395-25395/com.test.test D/Animation: interpolatedTime = 0.017721295
02-22 13:14:44.183 25395-25395/com.test.test D/Animation: interpolatedTime = 0.0656842
02-22 13:14:44.198 25395-25395/com.test.test D/Animation: interpolatedTime = 0.14644662
02-22 13:14:44.218 25395-25395/com.test.test D/Animation: interpolatedTime = 0.2522707
02-22 13:14:44.233 25395-25395/com.test.test D/Animation: interpolatedTime = 0.36806342
```

This case stopped at 0.36 also AnimationListener.onAnimationEnd() is not called . Sometimes it works properly and reaches 1.0. Why this happens ? How to fix it ?

Comment: Please re-read the question and give us a clue where we'd start searching for the error you made.